# Statistical method for time-course data comparison

Tags: statistics

I have a question for statistical method which i cant find in my textbook. I want to compare data of two groups. For example, both group have data of day 0, but one group have data of day 2, and another day 6. How can I analyse the outcome with the data and the date? i.e. I want to show that the if data taken on day XX are YY, it has an impact on the outcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a repeated measures ANOVA in this case. However, since you don't have a complete dataset, day X and Y would be just operationalized as the endpoint of your dependent variable. If you'd have measures of all days I'd include.all of them in the analysis in order to fully compare the two timelines. You could then also compare the days of interest directly by using post-hoc tests (e.g. Bonferroni)